# Is it computable to find the cardinality of intersection of two recursively enumerable sets?

Tags: computability, undecidability, decidability

I am well aware that recursively enumerable sets (which are subsets of $\mathbb N$) are closed under intersection. What is more interesting is whether or not the cardinality of the intersection is computable/decidable?

That is, given two recursively enumerable sets $A$, $B$, is $|A \cap B|$ always decidable/computable (provided we know what $|A|$ and $|B|$ are, even if they are infinite)?

My first hunch is that this is equivalent to the halting problem for Turing Machines, but how would I show this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "given" in `given two recursively enumerable sets A, B`?  If you mean that you know the algorithms that enumerate the sets, you can't even say what $|A|$ is.

Comment: Are you saying that the cardinality is in general undecidable? "Given" as in for ANY two such sets.

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs for your desired algorithm? You can't say that inputs are sets $A$ and $B$ since they can potentially have infinite sizes. If your inputs are enumerators for $A$ and $B$, then you can't even tell what the cardinalities of these languages are (in case if they are finite).

Comment: @Dmitry To clarify (revised my question),   if we have an algorithm (or better yet a Turing Machine) which determines if $x \in A \cap B$, I would like to solve the question of "how many" such $x$ will the Turing Machine will halt / algorithm will say "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

Claim: A  finite recursively-enumerable set is decidable.
Proof: In fact, a finite set is decidable.

Claim: It is computable to find $|A\cap B|$ given two finite sets $A$ and $B$.
Proof: List all elements in $A$. For each one of them, check whether it is in $B$. Return the number of all elements that are found in $B$.

Claim: It is not computable to find $|A\cap B|$ given two recursively-enumerable sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|$ is finite and $|B|$ is infinite.
Proof: For the sake of contradiction suppose algorithm $M$ finds $|A\cap B|$ given such $A$ and $B$. Let us solve the halting problem, as you expected.
Let $X$ be an arbitrary Turing machine and $w$ be an arbitrary input.
Let $M_1$ be a Turing machine that halts only when the input is $w$. Let $M_\infty$ be a Turing machine that always halts except when the input is $w$, at which time $X$ behaves the same as $X$ upon input $w$. Note that $|L(M_1)|=1$ is finite and $|L(M_\infty)|$ is infinite.
Apply $M$ to $L(M_1)$ and $L(M_\infty)$. If $|L(M_1)\cap L(M\infty)|=1$, then $X$ halts upon $w$. Otherwise, $|L(M_1)\cap L(M_\infty)|=0$, and $X$ loops forever upon $w$.  $\quad\checkmark$

Corollary: It is not computable to find $|A\cap B|$ given two recursively-enumerable sets $A$ and $B$ with known cardinalities.

Comment: What is $L$ supposed to mean ?

Comment: $L(T)$ for a Turing machine $T$ is the language accepted by $T$.